# Integração com story do Instagram

Tags: api, instagram-api

estou querendo saber se é possível fazer uma integração com a API do Instagram, para criar story personalizados com dados de cada um que compartilha, algo muito semelhante aos compartilhamentos de retrospectivas do Spotify. E como isso pode funcionar.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Existem bibliotecas que permitem diversas interações com posts e stories do Instagram, não encontrei nenhuma que automaticamente pega os dados de stories, mas encontrei bibliotecas que permitem o download de posts ou stories e a partir daquilo você pode usar alguma ferramenta para analisar a imagem e pegar os dados que você procura.

[Instagram Private API](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/ping-instagram_private_api-python-third-party-apis-wrappers)
[Docs - Instagram Private API](https://instagram-private-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Essa biblioteca permite que você poste uma foto ou vídeo nos stories ou no feed, permite curtir e descurtir posts, baixar comentários postados em qualquer post, postar ou deletar comentários, seguir e deixar de seguir usuários e etc.

[Instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/)

Essa segunda biblioteca foca principalmente no download de conteúdo, ela pode baixar perfis inteiros, stories, posts, mídia salva, hashtags usadas nos posts, comentários, dados de localização geográfica e etc.
Ela também detecta mudanças de nome dos perfis.

[Instauto](https://github.com/mifi/instauto)

Essa biblioteca foca mais no manipulamento dos seguidores de uma conta, seja as contas que você segue ou contas que te seguem, você pode ver quem você segue e não te segue de volta e vise-versa.

Resumidamente é isso, como eu disse no início você pode fazer uma "retrospectiva" usando cada biblioteca para:

- Baixar posts, stories, lista de seguidores ou todo o perfil
- Baseado no conteúdo que você baixou você pode manipular essas imagens ou procurar certo tipos de dados através de bibliotecas de manipulação de imagens
- A partir dos dados obtidos você pode gerar um vídeo ou post com gráficos ou um dashboard, gerando uma espécie de retrospectiva.

Aliás esqueci de avisar sobre a questão da linguagem de programação, as duas primeiras bibliotecas ([Instagram Private API](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/ping-instagram_private_api-python-third-party-apis-wrappers) e a [Instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/)) são bibliotecas de Python e a [Instauto](https://instaloader.github.io/) é uma biblioteca de Node.js